# calculate weighted.mean() for X variable with two W variables

Tags: r, dplyr, weighted-average

I have an issue where I am trying to transform a data frame into a summarized data frame with total sums and weighted averages based on multiple columns...

Below is an example of what I am doing...

```
df <- data.frame('title' = c("X", "Y", "Z", "X", "Y", "Z"),'date' = c("2020-01-01", "2020-01-01", "2020-01-01", "2020-01-02", "2020-01-03", "2020-01-02"),'weight1' = c(84024, 54241, 106601, 65382, 337007, 687682),'weight2' = c(30, 30, 30, 15, 15, 15),'metric1' = c(3.08, 0.964, 0.839, 1.60, 0.839, 0.648),'metric2' = c(588.03, 298.26, 13.95, 104.29, 10.51, 72.53))

agg = df %>% 
          group_by(df$date, df$title) %>%
          summarise(total_weight1 = sum(weight1, na.rm=TRUE), # total sum
          total_weight1 = sum(weight2, na.rm=TRUE), # total sum
          mean_metric1 = weighted.mean(x = metric1, w = c(weight1, weight2), na.rm=T), # weighted avg
          mean_metric2 = weighted.mean(x = metric2, w = c(weight1, weight2), na.rm=T)) # weighted avg
```

But of course, I get an error message:

> `Error in` summarise()`:`
>
> `Problem while computing` mean_metric1 = weighted.mean(x = metric1, w = c(weight1, weight2), na.rm = T)`. The error occurred in group 1: df$date = "2020-01-01", df$title = "X".`
>
> `Caused by error in` weighted.mean.default()`:`
>
> `! 'x' and 'w' must have the same length`

Is it possible to calculate the weighted average of a value based on two columns? I've tried finding other sources to validate this calculation manually but have failed...

I'm also not sure if calculating this all in the same data frame is the right way to go. Any guidance would be appreciated.

I've tried other sources and functions including rowwise() and mutate() but I keep running into the same issue that my 'x' and 'w' need to have the same length...

Comment: `w` should be a single numeric vector

Comment: According to documentation `w - a numerical vector of weights the same length as x giving the weights to use for elements of x.`.  Based on the example, you have only one observation per row because of grouping and this will also result in length difference

Comment: Please consider to provide your expected output.  here, there is only a single observation per group.  The code can work if you replicate i.e. `df %>% group_by(date, title) %>% summarise(total_weight = sum(weight1, na.rm = TRUE), across(starts_with('metric'), ~ weighted.mean(rep(.x, 2), w = c(weight1, weight2), na.rm = TRUE), .name = "mean_{.col}"), .groups = 'drop')`, but I don't think that is the expected

Answer (score 0):

Maybe multiplying the weights vectors will do what you except

```r
agg = df %>% 
  group_by(date, title) %>%
  summarise(
    total_weight1 = sum(weight1, na.rm=TRUE), # total sum
    total_weight1 = sum(weight2, na.rm=TRUE), # total sum
    mean_metric1 = weighted.mean(x = metric1, w = weight1 * weight2, na.rm=T), # weighted avg
    mean_metric2 = weighted.mean(x = metric2, w = weight1 * weight2, na.rm=T)) # weighted avg

agg

# A tibble: 6 × 5
# Groups:   df$date [3]
#   `df$date`  `df$title` total_weight1 mean_metric1 mean_metric2
#   <chr>      <chr>              <dbl>        <dbl>        <dbl>
# 1 2020-01-01 X                     30        3.08         588. 
# 2 2020-01-01 Y                     30        0.964        298. 
# 3 2020-01-01 Z                     30        0.839         14.0
# 4 2020-01-02 X                     15        1.6          104. 
# 5 2020-01-02 Z                     15        0.648         72.5
# 6 2020-01-03 Y                     15        0.839         10.5
```

It's equivalent to weigh the variable by `weight1` then by `weight2`

```r
agg2 <- df %>% 
  group_by(date, title) %>%
  summarise(
    total_weight1 = sum(weight1, na.rm=TRUE), # total sum
    total_weight1 = sum(weight2, na.rm=TRUE), # total sum
    mean_metric1 = mean(((metric1 * weight1/sum(weight1)) * weight2)/sum(weight2), na.rm=T), # weighted avg computed by hand
    mean_metric2 = mean(((metric2 * weight1/sum(weight1)) * weight2)/sum(weight2), na.rm=T)) # weighted avg computed by hand

all.equal(agg, agg2)
# [1] TRUE
```